# jsonp function is undefined

Tags: javascript, jsonp

```
(function () {

    function callbackF(data) {
        eval(data.script);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        if (url.indexOf('.html') > 0) {
            var gt_widget_id = document.createElement('div');
            gt_widget_id.setAttribute('id', 'gt_widget_0');
            var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
            comments.parentNode.insertBefore(gt_widget_id, comments);
            var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('src', "http://dev.example.com/wp/wpregister.asp?callback=callbackF&ver=2.5&url=" + encoded_url);
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("id", "grazit_script");
            document.getElementById("gt_widget_0").parentNode.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
})();
```

The html is not relevant to the question, the tag does get appended and json return is just after the call, the console tells me that callbackF is undefined? why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is that?

Because you need to define your `callbackF` function outside of the closure:

```
function callbackF(data) {
    eval(data.script);
}

(function () {
    window.onload = function () {
        if (url.indexOf('.html') > 0) {
            var gt_widget_id = document.createElement('div');
            gt_widget_id.setAttribute('id', 'gt_widget_0');
            var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
            comments.parentNode.insertBefore(gt_widget_id, comments);
            var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('src', "http://dev.example.com/wp/wpregister.asp?callback=callbackF&ver=2.5&url=" + encoded_url);
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("id", "grazit_script");
            document.getElementById("gt_widget_0").parentNode.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
})();
```

Alternatively you could define your `callbackF` function on the `window` scope so that it is accessible from the outside of the closure:

```
(function () {
    window.callbackF = function(data) {
        eval(data.script);
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        if (url.indexOf('.html') > 0) {
            var gt_widget_id = document.createElement('div');
            gt_widget_id.setAttribute('id', 'gt_widget_0');
            var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
            comments.parentNode.insertBefore(gt_widget_id, comments);
            var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('src', "http://dev.example.com/wp/wpregister.asp?callback=callbackF&ver=2.5&url=" + encoded_url);
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("id", "grazit_script");
            document.getElementById("gt_widget_0").parentNode.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: hmmm.. thanks Darin, i thought you answer only asp.net mvc question..I will try your method. is it because i wrapped the whole thing in a closure?

Comment: Yes, it's because you wrapped your entire method in a closure meaning that this function can only be called from inside this closure. Except that you are never calling this function inside the closure. You are calling a server side endpoint which returns JSONP which itself is calling the function. And, no, I am not answering only ASP.NET MVC questions.